# .toggle display:none not working

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, hide, show

I have a basic toggle script and right now when I add the display none and click the button it does not display the content that is hidden.

When I remove the `display:none` it shows the carat and when I click the button it hides it. I want it to have the reverse effect. I want the caret to be hidden and when I click the button I want it to appear.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $("span").toggle();
});
```

```css
.caret {
  display: none;
}
.caret:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: -20px;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="button"><a href="#tabs1">WHAT'S IN THE BAG</a>
  </li>
  <li class="button"><a href="#tabs3">PLAYER HISTORY</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<span class="caret"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question, your intending something this..

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $("span").toggle();
});
```

```css
.caret {
  display: none;
}
.caret:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: -20px;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="button"><a href="#tabs1">click me to toggle span caret</a>
  </li>
  <li class="button"><a href="#tabs3">click me to toogle span caret</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<span class="caret">i appeared.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $("span").toggleClass('caret');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the span to a div fixed the problem, but you can't really see it because the `.caret` class is white, so in my case, I made it black so it's visible.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".caret").toggle();
});
```

```css
.caret {
  display:none;
}
.caret:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: -20px;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #000;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="button"><a href="#tabs1">WHAT'S IN THE BAG</a>
  </li>
  <li class="button"><a href="#tabs3">PLAYER HISTORY</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="caret"></div>
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve but when I put this code in, it does not work on my end. When I click the button it does not display the caret. Perhaps there's some other code from making it not appear?

Comment: Silly question, but possible: When you check the element in your browser's inspector, are you seeing display:block on the `<div class="caret">`? If so, are you using a white border on white background? ;)

Comment: Don't see a display:block in inspector and the caret I am trying to display is over an dark image.

Comment: It's weird, when I remove the display:none from .caret it works but works backwards. I want it hide the caret default then show it on click. Very frustrating. Thanks for the help so far, I appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any other CSS that would be conflicting with this CSS? Anything that has a display:none !important ? It's hard to debug further without seeing the full CSS and JS you're dealing with. It sounds like something else is conflicting with it. 

EDIT: From your description, it definitely sounds like some other CSS is involved, causing it to be display block.

Have you tried using just this code and removing other JS functionality? Another function may not be working and would cause this function to not work.

Comment: It could be a number of things. This is code is just a small portion of the page. Could a display:block in any of the css cause it to not work properly?

Comment: Anything that could reference the .caret class would affect it. When you inspect the element `.caret`, before you click on the button, what is currently setting it to `display:block` ?